# How to find the Parent Component name in ReactJS v16.11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a one react component which is nested inside a multi-level components and each of these components are getting a props from their parent components. As it was multi level nesting, I lost track of the parent component.

So, are there any ways to find, from which parent component we are getting the props to its child?

I tried with the below code. But it is not working.

```
this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance
```

Scenario:
First Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SecondLevelComponent from './SecondLevelComponent'

export class FirstLevelComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SecondLevelComponent data="From Main Parent Component" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FirstLevelComponent
```

Second Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'

export class SecondLevelComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent data2={this.props.data}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SecondLevelComponent
```

Child Component:

```
export class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>FROM PARENT TO CHILD {this.props.data2}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ChildComponent
```

Comment: If your solution had involved something like `_reactInternalInstance`, it's plain wrong to begin with.

Comment: Anyway, _why_ do you need to know the parent? Your examples don't show any need for that.

Comment: I do not know about any commands that is used for that but you can do back tracking.Search where your child component is used then you will find its parent. Search that parent and then you will find that components parent.By search I meant search in your code editor.